# Consolidate paired list with regular expression

Tags: regex

I've a list which I want to consolidate matching pairs:

input:

```
(A1, B1, C1) (A2, B2, C2)
```

output:

```
(A1 A2, B1 B2, C1 C2)
```

I've tried expression like these:

- find:  `\((([^,]+)([, ]*))+\) \((([^,]+)[, ]*)+\)`
- replace to: `($1 $3 $4)`
- https://regex101.com/r/sMjiO9/1

However those capture only last elements of the lists, and not all of them.

How I can match all pairs? (number of pairs is variable)

Comment: Does it _have_ to be a regex only?

Comment: I'd use it mainly in Excel (through regex add-in), but sometimes in other tools too. I know in Excel I could write a macro for it too, however now I'm interested in the regex solution.

Comment: If the number of columns is variable, I suspect it's impossible to do with any flavour of regex. OTOH, it should be easy to do in code. And if each item was its own cell in Excel, it'd be a single "Transpose" button.

Comment: (e.g. if this were a Ruby script, it would be `data.scan(/\(.+?\)/).map{|i| i.scan(/[^(), ]/)}.transpose.map{|i| i.join(" ")}.join(", ").then{|i| "(#{i})"}`)

Comment: I don't think it possible with variable number of columns. Here is a solution for 3 columns: https://regex101.com/r/sMjiO9/2